# remote ssh command not exiting

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I have a restart script written in ruby

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "#{DIR}/etc/control_helper"


###### MAIN program ################
case action
    when 'start'
         .....

    when 'stop'
          .....
    when 'restart'
        kill_the_old_process_if_needed(PORT_NUM, APP_NAME, APP_FILE_NAME)

        new_pid = start_a_new_process!(ENVIRONMENT, PORT_NUM, APP_FILE_NAME)
#here there is an **exit(0)**
        check_for_success_in_starting_new_process!(hostname, new_pid) 

end
```

running the code from the local machine works:

```
ruby etc/control_app.rb restart production
```

but running it from remote ssh (jenkins machine, after code change)
doesn't exit .

```
gcloud compute ssh remote_server --zone us-central1-a --command "cd /path/to/app; ruby etc/control_app.rb restart production"
```

1. if i edit the script and put `exit(0)` at first then it exits.
2. I know it get to the exit(0) because I have placed a print directly above it.

Answer (score 0):

eventually it was the actual script. 
it was running a python script

```
PYTHON_ENV=#{environment} nohup python #{APP_FILE_NAME}  > #{environment}.log
```

added & at the end

```
PYTHON_ENV=#{environment} nohup python #{APP_FILE_NAME}  > #{environment}.log &
```